# How query a MySQL in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to link my asp.net Formview to a MySQL database, but with no success.

Take a look at my code and please tell my where is my mistake:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ImageID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            ImageID:
            <asp:Label ID="ImageIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>' />
            <br />
            Title:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
            <br />
            Description:
            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            Title:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
            <br />
            Description:
            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            ImageID:
            <asp:Label ID="ImageIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>' />
            <br />
            Title:
            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
            <br />
            Description:
            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="New" Text="New" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cmsConnectionString %>" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbimages] ([ImageID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (ImageID, Title, Description)" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cmsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ImageID, Title, Description FROM tbimages" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbimages] SET [Title] = ?, [Description] = ? WHERE [ImageID] = ?">

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImageID" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImageID" Type="Int64" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i already define my connection string in the web config :

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cmsConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=123;database=cms" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Please if you have any idea to solve this let me know.

Comment: what is the error message? and where?

Comment: the error is in the insert .

it's giving me every thing but when i'm trying to insert new record it's giving me this error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[tbimages] ([ImageID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (ImageID, Title, Descripti' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the Insert Command like so

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbimages] ([ImageID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (? , ? , ?)"
```

**UPDATED :**

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbimages] ([ImageID], [Title], [Description]) 
 VALUES (?ImageID , ?Title , ?Description)"
```

Comment: i tried this one before and it gives me another error :

Parameter '?' must be defined.!!!

Answer (score 0):

check the insert command definition of your datasource. See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insertcommand.aspx

Comment: my problem is with the insert statement>  i tried so many ways 

and the link you gave me it's for MSSQL not MySQL

thank you

Comment: did you try to append the parameters in the INSERT sytax with an "@"?

Comment: Well it does not take parameternames as placeholders but as values. So prepending them with '@' should help. At this stage it should not matter, if MSSQL or MySQL is at the end of the line ...